# How can I generally determine which bonds are longest/shortest in a molecule?

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

My task is to arrange the bonds from longest to shortest. Although I have the answer (C,D,B,A), I'm having a very hard time understanding how to derive this answer. Any clues would be helpful, especially those that help me in other related problems.

Comment: From periodic table, the atomic radius $r_C>r_N>r_F$. Therefore C>B,D>A. From conjugation effect, we expect nitrogen in B and D are sp2 and sp3. The more s, the shorter. Therefore D>B.

Comment: I have my final exam tomorrow and this was on a previous exam. So it's not homework, but I really need to understand the "why" behind the problem.

Comment: Is my explanation reasonable?

Comment: I'm not sure about the "conjugation effect" part, do you mind clearing that up?

Comment: If the orbitals in nitrogen (the near benzene one) and benzene are coplanar, they will conjugate each other. If the nitrogen adopts sp2 hybridazation for s and two p, one p left. That p will be coplanar with the benzene ring. Is this explanation reasonable?

Comment: Coplanar atoms are the atoms that have the double bond, and all of the atoms directly attached to them.

Answer (score 5):

Because atomic radii of elements tend to decrease across a period ([source](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/atoms/properties/atradius.html)), and bond length increases with atomic radius, the bond lengths are expected to decrease in the following order: C (C-C bond) > B, D (C-N) > A (C-F).

The difference between B and D is that in D, the nitrogen is $sp^3$-hybridized, while in B, it is $sp^2$-hybridized due to conjugation of its lone pair with the aromatic ring 2. This results in partial double bond character of the C(ring 2)-N bond, similar to aniline:

[image]

More $s$ character leads to [shorter bonds](http://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2010/10/13/sigma-bonds-come-in-six-varieties-pi-bonds-come-in-one/), and therefore the C-N bond B is shorter than D.

In summary, the bond lengths decrease in the following order: C > D > B > A.